# How to set the Task priority in C#

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am writing SharePoint workflows to my organization where i need to create the workflow tasks and set their priority to the given value (High, Medium and Low). I am able to change all other task proprties like "Assign To" or "Expected Date" but not "Priority". Please let me know if any one have any solution.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,
      But it was my mistake. When i set the value it exatly what in the drop down, it went fine.